# Concurrency issues with adding/removing from HashMap with Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having an issue removing from and adding to a HashMap that I'm storing as a field in a Firebase object.

I start with adding a key: `{key1=true}`

Then I delete a key while adding another one: `{key1=true, key2=true}` -> `{key2=true}`.

So I'm expecting the end result to be just `key2` but what I'm getting is empty `{}`. I understand how it is happening but fail to understand how to fix this. The issue is that I'm doing the remove in a callback, which is occurring after the add.

Do I just have to refactor my code so that the remove doesn't happen in a callback? This sounds like a common issue, or are people just designing their code architecture better than I am?

Comment: Instead of describing your code, create a minimal snippet of code that reproduces the problem. Most of us here read code easier than words. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

For posterity's sake - I do really love the convenience of a HashMap but there is a concurrency issue with HashMap (setting the whole hashmap overwrites any other values that you may be setting concurrently).

I mistakenly had been setting the whole HashMap when I went to go `updateChildren()` so I wrote a simple wrapper to handle the adding/removing of entries in the HashMap:

```
protected void updateFirebase(String FIELD, HashMap<String, Boolean> hashMap, String hashKey) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (Object k : hashMap.keySet()) {
      if (TextUtils.equals((String) k, hashKey)) {
        found = true;
      }
    }
    if (found) { // item being added
      HashMap<String, Object> addItem = new HashMap<>();
      addItem.put(hashKey, hashMap.get(hashKey));
      new Firebase(getObjectUrl()).child(this.key).child(FIELD).updateChildren(
        addItem
      );
    } else { // item being removed
      new Firebase(getObjectUrl()).child(this.key).child(FIELD).child(hashKey).removeValue();
    }
  }
```

So this instead will update the entry alone as opposed to trying to update a whole subtree - which removes the issue of concurrently updating with bad stale HashMap states.